# Tmux regex or wildcard search

Tags: tmux

I can do `ctrl+b [ ctrl+r` to search upwards through my tmux window.

But is it possible to find a line containing, say, `foo` *and* `bar` but not contiguously?

I'm imagining doing something like:

```
:foo.*bar
```

I'm searching through logs outputted to stdout, so the results have to be on one line to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

`C-b C-r` doesn't do anything by default, it would be helpful if you show what you have bound it to, although I assume it is some variant of `copy-mode \; send -X search-backward ...`.

Anyway, searching with regular expressions is supported since tmux 3.1.

Comment: Oops: I meant `C-b [ C-r`. So how would I search for what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you are using `C-r` in copy mode you will be using incremental search which doesn't support regex at the moment. You need to use the `search-backward` command instead (in copy mode), for example from the command prompt: `C-b : send -X search-backward foo.*bar`. You can bind this to a key, look at the default `/` and `?` key bindings in the `copy-mode-vi` key table.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer. If you update your answer to include this comment, I'll accept and upvote.